# Sql Server 2008 - BEFORE triggers?

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

I've long been waiting for BEFORE triggers. But we have some systems which are written in ORACLE. When a potential new client asked why, our president told them that it was because there are no BEFORE triggers in Sql Server (among other things).

To this, the client responded, "Yes, in 2008 you CAN write BEFORE triggers."

Now I've heard nothing of this, not at the launch events, not in the "what's new" lists online. As far as I know, there still are no proper BEFORE triggers. Am I wrong in this?

Are BEFORE triggers actually hidden in 2008 somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your client is wrong :-) Even in SQL Server 2008, there's no "BEFORE INSERT" triggers.

As Charles Bretana already mentioned: you get AFTER INSERT or INSTEAD OF INSERT triggers, but no full-fledged BEFORE triggers in SQL Server.

It's a fact for now - gotta live with it and hope for SQL Server 2008 R2 ! :-)

Marc

Comment: That's what I thought. I've been waiting and watching long for these, so I was quite surprised to hear this. I thought they were probably ... mistaken, but I figured I would check anyway. 
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server (since SQL 2k5 I believe) has what's called 'Instead Of' Triggers which is, in a way, a Before trigger.

Comment: Yah, INSTEAD OFs *sort* of let you do the same thing, but you wind up having to completely recode whatever SQL statements were supposed to take effect. This leads to LOADS more code in the db, and a MUCH higher potential for bugs to creep in. For example, if a table has a new field added, or one removed, now you need to update the instead of triggers to handle the new (or missing) field. The real power of a BEFORE trigger is for scrubbing your data BEFORE it ever enters the db, resulting in higher data integrity without putting undue burden on the front-end code.